# Convert two columns in spark data frame into Map type?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two columns for example

```
 Code   Department
    E.          ECE
    C.          CSE
```

I want to convert this as map type like below

```
Map( E -> ECE, C -> CSE)
```

Note - Currently using spark 2.2 with scala.

Answer (score 11):

Given that input *dataframe* and *schema* as below

```
+----+----------+
|Code|Department|
+----+----------+
|E.  |ECE       |
|C.  |CSE       |
+----+----------+

root
 |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Department: string (nullable = true)
```

You can convert to rdd and convert each row to Map inside map function and finally collect as Map

```
df.rdd.map(row => (row.getString(0) -> row.getString(1))).collectAsMap()
```

which is your desired output

```
Map(E. -> ECE, C. -> CSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to convert to RDD, if you can use `withColumn` and `map` function directly.

```
df.withColumn("map", map('Code, 'Department))
```

Comment: This would give a column named map of type Map and would not give actual Map type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `map`function. Arguments must be columns. Odd positions will take the value of the column as the key, so you can use `lit` with the name of the column. Even positions will take the value of the column as the values for the `key` specified just before.

```
df.withColumn("map", map(lit('Code'), col('Code'), lit('Department'), col('Department')))
```

However, not that Maps in spark can only contain key and values from the same type (one type for keys, another for values), so if you map columns with String type and numeric types, numeric types will automatically be converted to String.